# How to run a custom gradle plugin that depends on test task

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I'm currently attempting use this library to run ui tests on android.
https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android

I run the tests using:

```
./gradlew verifyMode screenshotTests
```

on root of directory.

However, all I want to run is:

```
./gradlew test
```

And I would like it to run the screenshot tests as well as my ui tests. Is this possible todo? My current build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot:plugin:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "sample.TestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile project(':library')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.17'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle executes the tasks specified as command line arguments and their dependencies. If you only want to specify the `test` task in your command, but still execute the tasks `verifyMode` and `screenshotTests`, you can register these tasks as dependencies of the `test` task:

```
test {
    dependsOn 'verifyMode', 'screenshotTests'
}
```

However, please note that now every execution of the `test` task will also cause `verifyMode`, `screenshotTests` and their respective dependencies to run. Since the `test` task is a dependency of the `build` task, calling `gradle build` will also run `verifyMode` and `screenshotTests`, what you might not want. As a solution, you can define a *dummy* task, that collects all your test tasks:

```
task allTests {
    dependsOn 'test', 'verifyMode', 'screenshotTests'
}
```

Now you could call `gradle allTests` and Gradle would execute just the tasks you want to be executed.